# Declining "dulcis" in context

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, adjective, declension

I want to translate the phrase

> It's just like a big recorder

where "recorder" is the musical instrument.  The generic Latin for "flute" seems to be "tibia" (pipe), so I settled on using the Latin for the Italian "flauto dolce", which at first glance would be "tibia dulcis" but I fear I don't have the right inflection on "sweet".  My uneducated attempt is:

> Tamquam (or possibly Quasi) magna tibia dulcis est

Is this even close, or is there a better way of expressing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Quasi* is "as if"; for this, I'd use *similis*, "like". I think I'd also use *longa* instead of *magna*, to express size rather than quality.

The older (pre-Augustan) way to use *similis* is with the genitive, which would be *longae tibiae dulcis*. The newer (post-Augustan) way is with the dative, which would be *longae tibiae dulcī*.

EDIT: Vincenzo Oliva in the comments suggests using *recta* "straight" instead of *dulcis*; if you go with this, it would be a *longae tibiae rectae* in either case.

Comment: Apparently the Latin name for the instrument is _tibia recta_: _tibia_ [corresponds](https://www.dizionario-latino.com/dizionario-italiano-latino.php?lemma=FLAUTO100) to Italian _flauto_, and _recta_ reflects an alternative to the name "flauto dolce" (i.e. _flauto diritto_, as can be seen on the [Wiki page](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flauto_dolce)  ).

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Nice find! Added.